# How to filter list of objects with child collection by list of strings

Tags: linq

I have two lists, a list strings called sectionRoles and a list of User objects called appUsers.  The User class has a collection of Role classes. I want to filter the appUsers list where any of their Role.RoleName properties has an entry in the sectionRoles list.

How would I do that?  Preferably in method syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple enough:

```
var usersWithRoles = appUsers.Where(user => 
              user.Roles.Any(role => sectionRoles.Contains(role.RoleName))).ToList();
```

This checks for each user in `appUsers` if `Any` of it's `Role`s has a `RoleName` that is contained in the `sectionRoles` list.